# Verbatim string literal not interpreting html

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my controller action, I am sending a message to a view -

```
model.Result = ex.Message;
model.Result = model.Result + @" If you would like to create one, please <a href="something"> click here </a>";
```

So, I want the message to show up like so -

```
The member doesn't exist. If you would like to create one, please click here.
```

But what actually shows up is

```
The member doesn't exist. If you would like to create one, please <a href> click here </a>.
```

So, I have 2 questions -

1) Why is the verbatim string literal not evaluating the html.

2) Is there a better way of doing this? I don't like having html in my controllers, but I also don't want to over architect things for a line of html.

Comment: "Why is the verbatim string literal not evaluating the html." - string literals don't evaluate *anything*... they are.... literals; that's all they do... I suspect the real question here might be "why is MVC/razor escaping my string, when I want to treat it as trusted html?" - in which case Chris Pratt has you covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor automatically HTML-encodes strings for security (to prevent script injection). You need to use `Html.Raw` if you want the actual HTML.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.ResultMessage)
```

Comment: nit: it is probably html-encoding this, not url-encoding it; but: yes

Comment: If I use `@Html` in my controller, it gives me an error saying that it doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Doh. Sorry. Head thought one thing and hands typed another. Fixed.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Do you know why that's happening?

Comment: By design. It's very much intentional. Again, allowing any random string to be output would open a huge security hold in your application. They've provided `Html.Raw` so you can still output HTML *if you want*, but the important part there is that it requires you making a conscious choice to do so, fully aware of any potential side-effects (i.e. don't use `Html.Raw` with user-submitted content, unless you implicitly trust said users, such as staff of your organization)

Comment: @ChrisPratt If I use `@Html` in my controller, it gives me an error saying that it doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Not in your controller, in your view. Where you want to output `ResultMessage`, instead of doing something like `@Model.ResultMessage`, you do `@Html.Raw(Model.ResultMessage)`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Gotcha. I changed it to `@Html.Raw(Model.ResultMessage)` now, but it is still displaying the tags in the view.